# Вывести последние записи от пользователей

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, Мне нужно вывести некую статистику от всех пользователей, но только их последнюю запись в БД. (Всего таких пользователей примерно 150)

В принципе она получается.

```
SELECT * FROM events t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT userid , MAX( dateline_from ) AS dateline_from 
FROM events
GROUP BY 1 
)t2 ON ( t2.userid = t1.userid ) AND ( t2.dateline_from = t1.dateline_from )
```

Вопрос в том, как сюда внедрить, чтобы вместо userid брался ник пользователя из другой таблицы с таким же полем userid (но только из таблицы user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, t3.name FROM events t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userid , MAX( dateline_from ) AS dateline_from 
    FROM events
    GROUP BY 1 
)t2 ON ( t2.userid = t1.userid ) AND ( t2.dateline_from = t1.dateline_from )
LEFT JOIN user AS t3 ON t3.userid = t1.userid
```

Оно, не?

Comment: Спасибо, оно)

Answer (score 0):

в конце прописать DESC LIMIT 20?????

Comment: Что такое `DESC`? Если это для сортировки, то отдельно без `ORDER BY` оно не используется.

`LIMIT 20` ограничит выдачу 20-ю первыми записями. Если нужно только первые 20 - ставьте